# þÿ getting appending to the beginig of the excel file causing regression

Tags: java, excel, csv, encoding, utf-16

I am reading Chinese and Spanish data from the Database and writing into CSV file. I am using UTF-16. when I open CSV file in Excel þÿ is getting prepended. How do I avoid writing þÿ into CSV?

```
FileOutputStream os =   new FileOutputStream("s.csv", false)
 CSVWriter out = new CSVWriter(
     new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-16"
                                )));
private void write(String[] values) throws IOException {    
        out.writeNext(values);
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question, adding the code that writes to the CSV, and mentioning any libraries that you are using for this.

Comment: I wonder if it is clever to remove the byte order mark from UTF-16 files ...

Comment: @Tom It would not be a good idea if you want the file to be portable across systems. But I wonder why one would want to write UTF-16 in the first place.

Comment: Could you try to use the tab character as a delimiter in your CSV file ?

Answer (score 2):

These two characters are the Byte Order Mark (for big endian) that can be used with the UTF-16 encoding.

To write without prepending the byte order mark, use the java.nio.Charset identified by UTF-16BE, not just UTF-16.